# ROS web video server

Tags: video, ros

I am trying to run web_video_server (https://github.com/RobotWebTools/web_video_server) for ROS.
catkin build was succesful, but I don't know how I can run this...
If I check the URL which is shown in the documentation, nothing happens.
I got an IP-Camera, and i can see the stream in rviz. So that works.

Because I am pretty new to ROS I would appreciate a realy "basic" answer or instruction how to do that. I can not find any tutorial or explanation to this problem.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for the late answer, but it may be useful for other guys.

You do not need to use any git. Just do (replace kinetic by your ros distro) :
sudo apt-get install ros-kinetic-web-video-server
Then to launch it `rosrun web_video_server web_video_server`

To publish image you can use `roslaunch openni2_launch openni2.launch`, to publish XtionProLive data for example, or `rosrun cv_camera cv_camera_node` if you have a classic monocular camera.

then go to 0.0.0.0:8080 in your favorite browser and you should be able to display your images

Answer (score 0):

You can run the server with: `rosrun web_video_server web_video_server`